# ssis package on catalog and on sql agent job(The sql agent job Error)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

An ssis (2012) package contains vb script to read a file is running fine and succeded on the catalog.When created as a part of a sql job it has been running for a while not giving any updates.It seems a file reading problem when running using job

The above probelm is resolved but not getting an error

The ssis package is running in the job .But It is failing in the script task step with this error `

```
"The script task uses version 14 script that is not supported in this release of integration service"`
```

It used to give same error when executing in Visual Studio and i resolved it by setting

```
Project property ->
Deployment Target Version change the Target Server Version to "SQL Server 2014."
```

Comment: If you look around you'll see this is almost always because the SQL Agent account doesn't have rights to do what it needs. Your mission is to find the SSIS logs and check them, and they will say the same thing.

Comment: When executed as a part of job it gives an error "The script task uses version 14 script that is not supported in this release of integration service"

Comment: The job refers the package in the integration service catlaog.It works fine ,When right click and execute the IS package from catalog !!

Comment: That's because when you do that it's running locally. When you run it in a job it runs on the server and it runs as a different sure. On the server it's using thew wrong SSIS runtime

Comment: I do not mean this ssis package is not running.It is failing in the script task step with this error The script task uses version 14 script that is not supported in this release of integration service"

Comment: Basically there is a version mismatch between Visual Studio and the SQL Server. What version of Visual Studio are you using? What version of SQL Server is the job running in? What version is the package? (as per here https://sqlstudies.com/2015/04/27/what-sql-version-is-my-ssis-package/ ). You need to either upgrade/downgrade the package or use a different DTExec.EXE on the server.